# Zoomable sunburst visualization without define size in children node in json file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I used this root = d3.hierarchy(root);    root.sum(d => d.size);

in my json i dont have the size value for children node, How can I generate proper d3 Zoomable sunburst visualization?

Here is my code

> const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight,
>   maxRadius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 5;
>
> const formatNumber = d3.format(',d');
>
> const x = d3.scaleLinear() .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]) .clamp(true);
>
> const y = d3.scaleSqrt() .range([maxRadius*.1, maxRadius]);
>
> const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
>
> const partition = d3.partition();
>
> const arc = d3.arc() .startAngle(d => x(d.x0)) .endAngle(d => x(d.x1))
>   .innerRadius(d => Math.max(0, y(d.y0))) .outerRadius(d => Math.max(0,
>   y(d.y1)));
>
> const middleArcLine = d => { const halfPi = Math.PI/2; const angles =
>   [x(d.x0) - halfPi, x(d.x1) - halfPi]; const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) +
>   y(d.y1)) / 2);
>
> const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2; const invertDirection
>   = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // On lower quadrants write text ccw if (invertDirection) { angles.reverse(); }
>
> const path = d3.path(); path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1],
>   invertDirection); return path.toString(); };
>
> const textFits = d => { const CHAR_SPACE = 6;
>
> const deltaAngle = x(d.x1) - x(d.x0); const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) +
>   y(d.y1)) / 2); const perimeter = r * deltaAngle;
>
> return d.data.name.length * CHAR_SPACE < perimeter; };
>
> const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg') .style('width', '100vw')
>   .style('height', '100vh') .attr('viewBox', `${-width / 2} ${-height /
>   2} ${width} ${height}`) .on('click', () => focusOn()); // Reset zoom
>   on canvas click
>
> d3.json('dummy3Copy.json', (error, root) => { if (error) throw error; 
>   //start custom code
>
> //end custom code    root = d3.hierarchy(root);    root.sum(d =>
>   d.size);
>
> const slice = svg.selectAll('g.slice')
>   .data(partition(root).descendants());
>
> slice.exit().remove();
>
> const newSlice = slice.enter() .append('g').attr('class', 'slice')
>   .on("mouseover", mouseover) .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc) .on('click',
>   d => { d3.event.stopPropagation(); focusOn(d); });
>
> newSlice.append('title') .text(d => d.data.name + '\n' + d.data.id);
>   //.on("mouseover", mouseover);
>
> newSlice.append('path') .attr('class', 'main-arc') .style('fill', d =>
>   color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name)) .attr('d', arc);
>
> newSlice.append('path') .attr('class', 'hidden-arc') .attr('id', (_,
>   i) => `hiddenArc${i}`) .attr('d', middleArcLine);
>
> const text = newSlice.append('text') .attr('display', d => textFits(d)
>   ? null : 'none');
>
> // Add white contour text.append('textPath')
>   .attr('startOffset','50%') .attr('xlink:href', (_, i) =>
>   `#hiddenArc${i}` ) .text(d => d.data.name) .style('fill', 'none')
>   .style('stroke', '#fff') .style('stroke-width', 5)
>   .style('stroke-linejoin', 'round');
>
> text.append('textPath') .attr('startOffset','50%') .attr('xlink:href',
>   (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}` ) .text(d => d.data.name); });
>
> var tooltip = d3.select("body")
>       .append("div")
>       .attr("id", "tooltip")
>       .style("position", "absolute")
>       .style("z-index", "10")
>       .style("opacity", 0);
>
> function format_description(d) {
>
> ```
>   return  '<b>' + d.name + '</b></br>'; } function mouseover(d) {
>  d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")             
>        tooltip.html(format_description(d));
>       return tooltip.transition()
>         .duration(50)
>         .style("opacity", 0.9);
> ```
>
> } function mouseOutArc(){
>       d3.select(this).attr("stroke","")
>       return tooltip.style("opacity", 0); } function focusOn(d = { x0: 0, x1: 1, y0: 0, y1: 1 }) { // Reset to top-level if no data point
>   specified
>
> const transition = svg.transition() .duration(750) .tween('scale', ()
>   => { const xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x0, d.x1]), yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y0, 1]); return t => { x.domain(xd(t));
>   y.domain(yd(t)); }; });
>
> transition.selectAll('path.main-arc') .attrTween('d', d => () =>
>   arc(d));
>
> transition.selectAll('path.hidden-arc') .attrTween('d', d => () =>
>   middleArcLine(d));
>
> transition.selectAll('text') .attrTween('display', d => () =>
>   textFits(d) ? null : 'none');
>
> moveStackToFront(d);
>
> //
>
> function moveStackToFront(elD) { svg.selectAll('.slice').filter(d => d
>   === elD) .each(function(d) { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); if (d.parent) { moveStackToFront(d.parent); } }) } }

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this "root = d3.hierarchy(root); root.sum(d => d.size);"
 with below code

> var root = d3.hierarchy(root, function(d) { return d.children })
>       .sum( function(d) {
>                   if(d.children) {
>                       return 0
>                   } else {
>                       return 1
>                   } });